# What would be the difference between WITH clause & temporary table?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, data-warehouse, temp-tables, with-clause

In layman terms, what would be the key differences between WITH clause & temporary table?

In which scenario it is better to use one over the other?

Comment: Key difference: the with clause has to be used directly in the associated query. With temp tables, you may use them during your session. So, their lifespan are different.

Answer (score 6):

[`WITH`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WITH_clause.html) clause is used in a select query generally when you have to perform some join on a couple of subqueries which contains complex clauses such as `HAVING` (though not necessarily). Generally speaking `WITH` clause can only be used in a `SELECT` statement.

But in a case where data has to be manipulated, meaning you want to change data on some condition or even would like to delete some rows again depending on some complex condition you would rather like to go with [`TEMP TABLE`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/merge-create-staging-table.html). Although most cases would be achieved by `WITH` it generally comes at a cost of some complex logic, in `TEMP` table you can have a couple of different SQL statements to achieve the same.

Also, `TEMP` table is generally used as a staging table rather than a view for `SELECT` query i.e. `TEMP` table are used when you want to load tons of data from `S3`, you might want to load the data into a temp table, analyze the data, remove redundancy and finally merge it into the original table in one go.

While `TEMP` table is transient only for the current session, `WITH` is always re-evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that the temporary table is a stored table. A CTE is more akin to a view, and helps you express your SQL in an easier to read, more logical way. The same differences apply between tables and views in that a table gives you the potential to do things in a performant way.

If you were building a very complex query or one that needs to be built in stages,  WITH clause/CTE would help you do that. However if you were looking to store data in a table to improve performance, a temporary table would be your best bet.
Similarly, a temporary table can be used again and again, so if you had the same code used in multiple queries, you might consider a temporary table rather than a CTE.